# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'. Flutter can't create release apk but debug apk ok

Tags: android, flutter, apk

When I using "**flutter build apk**" command it's give this error.

[image]

I can run on physical device so it can create debug apk and when I use "**flutter build apk --debug**" it's create debug apk in build folder.

I can't create release apk is there any advice?

Comment: Have you add your signing key? https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app

Comment: yes, I have key.jks file.